# HD Derivation Path with P-256 signature

Tags: ledger, wallets, cryptography, tezbox

Is it possible to use P-256 encryption system on a ledger nano with tezbox?

With Obsidian's command line tool, it is possible to use 3 types of signatures (Ed25519, Secp256k1, P-256). What are the HD Derivation Path on tezbox for those differents encryption system?

Answer (score 4):

TezBox currenty only supports the ed25519 curve, this is because the underlying library (eztz.js) only supports this curve. We are about to release support for the other two curves in eztz.js in the next few weeks, and will likely roll out support to TezBox after that.

The alternate HD paths will be available in the wallet after that, but currently you will need to use the tezos-client if you want to access them for now.